# IsDate function returns true but date conversion fails on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2016

I am upgrading a database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2016, and encountered an issue with a date conversion that has me stumped.

First, the date value is stored in an XML column and the value is "01/1/015".

This query will execute on the SQL Server 2005 database and convert the year to 2015.  However, when executing this query on the same data in SQL Server 2016, it will fail with this message:

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

```
select ISDATE(cd1.XmlData.value('(/Customer/Date/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)')) as 'IsDate',
    cd1.XmlData.value('(/Customer/Date/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as 'Date as varchar',
    cast(cd1.XmlData.value('(/Customer/Date/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Datetime) as 'Date as datetime'
from Cases c
INNER JOIN CaseData AS cd1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.CaseID = cd1.CaseID AND cd1.TabID = 'CUST' 
where c.CaseID = '123456'
```

I have compared database settings and server settings against both servers but have not found anything that looks to be relevant.

It seems odd that in SQL Server 2016, the IsDate function returns true but the conversion fails.  I have also tried converting to date using this line too, but it also fails: cd1.XmlData.value('(/CustomerInfo/ciEffectiveDate/text())[1]', 'datetime').

Has anyone else encountered this or knows how to deal with what I would consider an invalid date?

Comment: Is `01/1/015` a typo for `01/1/2015` or did someone, somewhere, seriously think this was a good idea over using ISO 8601?

Comment: I suspect it's a format issue. You could use `TRY_CONVERT` to get `NULL` for invalid dates (or dates which do not fit the format). Also, as a test, you could set the compatibility level of the 2016 database to 2005 (I think it's 90, but that's easily found).

Comment: I can't repro.  Both   select cast('01/1/015' as datetime) and select cast('01/1/2015' as datetime)  work for me on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3210089) - 13.0.4202.2.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: 2016 doesn't support compatibility levels lower than 100 (2008). But using the latest compat level and `TRY_CONVERT` (per your suggestion) is a far better idea, especially if you supply the third parameter indicating the format. Normalizing the data before processing is even better, of course.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Thanks for checking.  I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor).  Do you know what the difference is between SP1-GDR and SP1?  Also seems we are at a different patch level.  I'll ask our DBA to update to the latest level.

Comment: The GDR bit is irrelevant.  The version is 13.0.4422.0, which is SQL 2016 SP1 CU2 See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013106/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2016-sp1